# Django runserver on all ports?

Tags: django, django-manage.py

Why can't I run `python manage.py runserver` on all ports?

I understand this is probably a newbie question, but what prevents me from achieving this?

I would like to access my app without having to include the port, like a regular website

Comment: "[What is a tcp port?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_(computer_networking))"

Comment: Even if it were possible, there are up to 65,535 ports on a computer. You'll actually run `python manage.py runserver` on each one of them?

Comment: I purposedely made the title very "newbieish" in case other people have the same question, the actual question would be how to access django without a port

Comment: So how do you want to access your Django app? Without a port, as in "localhost" or "www.example.com"?

Comment: The development server is not supposed to be run in production. So you don't need to know this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***WARNING - Do not run the test server in production!***

The reason you have to type in the port when connecting to the test server is because it doesn't run on a standard web port being "http: 80 and https: 443". If you use the command below it will not require the port number be provided when connecting to the test server. Keep in mind that you will need root or sudo access and if something is already running on port 80 it will fail.

Runserver with port:
`python manage.py runserver -p 80`

Comment: Your advice should have been don't run the development server in production.

Comment: The OP didn't say they where trying to run it in production.

Comment: Yes, good point, but why would it need to run on all ports in development

Comment: You are also correct and adding a warning about it is a good idea. So I updated my response.

Answer (score 1):

Just run it on port 80 and you won't have to specify the port.

You can't blast it on all other ports because many, many other services already use those other ports. Network services need to have ports specified.

Comment: Your advice should have been don't run the development server in production.